# Connecting Android and Database

Tags: android, database

Hi I am new in android programming.I want to create a android application with Mysql database.I've used the following code but it won't work.What can I do please help me.

```
private static String url_create= "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create.php";
```

Comment: Please, more code, more infos ! The only advice i can tell you is that if you want to access your local computer from android, you should request 10.0.2.2 and not 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql does not work out of the box on Android! So you will not have a local MySql database on your phone.

For accessing remote Databases usually you will provide a backend that queries the database and delivers the data in the format of your choice (for instance json) to the android app.

So the Android App basically makes HTTP requests to your backened. The backend queries / manipulates the database and  returns the data as json. The application parse the json and displays the parsed data.

[Little tutorial](http://m-zeeshanarif.blogspot.it/2013/05/android-connecting-to-server-mysql.html) - its not the best code, but just to give you an idea.